# What does this syntax do: | select @{E={$_.PSComputerName}; L='Server'}, Name, ProcessId, PathName?

Tags: powershell, syntax, scripting, notation

I have a Powershell script where there's a line:

> `$MyServers | select @{E={$_.PSComputerName}; L='AX Server'}, Name, ProcessId, PathName`

What is the significance/function of this part? What does it do? Where can I understand the notation?

`@{E={$_.PSComputerName}; L='AX Server'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Viet's answer is not technically wrong, it doesn't really explain why that hashtable is being created as a parameter of the `Select-Object`.

It's generally referred to as a calculated property and it's used to customize the output of the object(s) you're selecting from. In your case, it's basically being used to rename an output column from `PSComputerName` to `AX Server`.

The `L` key of the hashtable is short for `Label` and the `E` key is short for `Expression`. So it is equivalent to writing this:

```
@{ Label='AX Server'; Expression={$_.PSComputerName} }
```

In other words, output a column called `AX Server` with a value that equals the `PSComputerName` property of the current object in the list (`$_`).

Calculated properties are often used to manipulate the data instead of just renaming columns. So you can do things like change the PSComputerName to upper case, do math on numeric values, or even combine multiple columns into one.

Comment: AH! This explains it very well. I thought `E` and `L` had to be short for something. So if there were 3 rows, the row header would be `AX Server` and each row would be whatever the computer name is. This code/function is designed to be executed remotely, so this makes more sense.

Comment: New insight.   Needed to try this one out for myself, and sure enough this is indeed the case.   Upvoted.

Comment: Yeah. You can stuff any PowerShell code you want in the Expression statement. Just remember that it will run for every single object being passed through the pipeline.

Comment: Believe it or not...I wrote the code years ago (in a moment of clarity) and today, couldn't figure it out that syntax I used.

Answer (score 2):

It creates a hashtable object where the key E will be populated with PSComputerName value from $MyServers and L will be 'AX Server'

```
PS C:\> @{E='Value 1'; L='Value 2'} | % { write-host $_.L }
Value 2

PS C:\> @{E='Value 1'; L='Value 2'} | Select-Object -Property *

IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : False
IsSynchronized : False
Keys           : {L, E}
Values         : {Value 2, Value 1}
SyncRoot       : System.Object
Count          : 2

PS C:\> @{E='Value 1'; L='Value 2'} | % { write-host $_.GetType().FullName }
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

Comment: So is it just adding a fixed constant of sorts to a `Format-Table` output?